# How to display a timer counting back 5 minutes?

Tags: c#, winforms

I added a timer to the form1 designer.

In the top of form1:

```
private int countdownSeconds = 300; // 5 minutes
private Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
```

form1 constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    timer1.Interval = 100; // Update every 100 milliseconds
    StartTimer();
    DownloadFolderViewerButtonStates();
    ResetUI();
    graphicsDrawer = new GraphicsDrawer();
    startTime = DateTime.Now;
}
```

the method StartTimer:

```
private void StartTimer()
{
    countdownSeconds = 300; // Reset the countdown time
    stopwatch.Restart();
    timer1.Start();
}
```

the timer tick event:

```
private async void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    countdownSeconds -= 100; // Subtract the timer interval (100 milliseconds) from the countdown

    if (countdownSeconds <= 0)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        radar = new Radar(downloadFolder);
        await radar.PrepareLinksAsync(); // Use await here
        DownloadFiles(radar.links);
        StartTimer(); // Restart the timer after the download is complete
    }

    TimeSpan remainingTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(countdownSeconds);

    // Display time with milliseconds
    lblTimer.Text = $"{remainingTime.Hours:D2}:{remainingTime.Minutes:D2}:{remainingTime.Seconds:D2}:{(int)remainingTime.TotalMilliseconds:D3}";
}
```

The problem is that on the milliseconds I see 3 digits like 000 and the digits change between 1 and 3 on the first zero digit like:  100 then "jump" to 300 or to 200 and so on between 1 and 3 on the last digits.

the minutes and seconds stay on 00:00

but I want it to be like a timer that count down 5 minutes including milliseconds , seconds , and minutes.

Comment: I really think this is overcomplicated. If you want to have a countdown starting 'now' and counting 5 mins, you can always init with `var target = now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)` and then just do `var countdown = target - now`  where you only update `now` with the current timestamp.

Comment: Also: You set `countdownSeconds = 300;` ( _in seconds_ ) but then you go on to treat those seconds as milliseconds : `countdownSeconds -= 100; // Subtract the timer interval (100 milliseconds) ...` ... that won't fly. **Mind your units** :)

Comment: @Fildor show how to reset inside the timer tick event and even outside the tick event please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one of the easiest ways to achive this is to use a seperate thread that always waits for the system to be idle and if its idle you could update the textbox:

```
var endTime = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
Thread countdownThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    var remaining = (endTime - DateTime.Now);
    while (remaining.TotalMilliseconds > 0)
    {
        remaining = (endTime - DateTime.Now);

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle, new Action(() =>//this needs to happen on the gui thread so we dispatch it
        {
            if (remaining.TotalMilliseconds > 0)
            {
               //update your Text box or MVVM depency property here
               tbTimer.Text = remaining.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                tbTimer.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0).ToString();
            }
        }));
    }

});
countdownThread.IsBackground = true;
countdownThread.Start();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your error is not minding your units.

In one place `countdownSeconds` is set to 300 **seconds**. But in the timer tick event handler - for some odd reason - you treat that number as **milliseconds**. Resulting in
a roll-over every 300 millis.

And then you parse those into a TimeSpan **FromMilliseconds**. So all you will ever see is 300ms, 200ms, 100ms and 0.

---

Now that we have identified the error, I'd suggest you don't do it like this *at all*.

Set a target timestamp ( e.g. "now" + 5 mins ) and in the tick handler, update via 'target - now'. To reset, set the target again to 'now + 5 mins'.

Comment: you have to cancel the timer if the value is negative. Similar like i did it in the other answer

Comment: Fildor show how to rest please.

Comment: this is working:  inside the timer tick event:  if (countdown <= TimeSpan.Zero)
{
    // Reset the target to 1 minute from now
    target = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
}